# Colimits in the category of $k$-topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, limits-colimits

Recall a [$k$-space](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compactly+generated+topological+space) $X$ is a topological space with the property that a subset is open if, and only if its intersection with any compact subspace is open in the subset topology. Let $k$**Top** be the full subcategory of **Top** consisting of the $k$-spaces and continuous maps between them.

There is a functor **Top** $\to$ $k$**Top** ($k$-ification) changing the topology slightly. We denote $Y_k$ the image of a topological space $Y$ under this functor. It has the property that if $X$ is a $k$-space, $Y$ is any topological space, and $f:X\to Y$ is any function, then $f$ is continuous if, and only if $f$ seen as a map $X\to Y_k$ is continuous.

In light of what we have said above, is it true that a colimit in $k$**Top** is the same as that colimit taken in **Top**? Namely, denote by $\iota:$ $k$**Top** $\to$ **Top** the inclusion. Let $D$ be a diagram in $k$**Top**. Is
$$\operatorname{colim}^{\textbf{Top}}\iota(D) \cong \iota(\operatorname{colim}^{k\textbf{Top}}D)$$
true?

Comment: Yes, since left adjoints preserve colimits.

Comment: In more detail, your second paragraph says that $\hom_{\mathbf{Top}}(\iota(X),Y) \cong \hom_{k\mathbf{Top}}(X,Y_k)$ and moreover these bijection are clearly natural (since they are identity at the level of functions). This means that $k$-ification is right adjoint to $\iota$ and hence $\iota$ preserves all colimits.

Comment: @Nex Ah, right! Now I feel kinda stupid. Thanks for the reminder. Please, write your comment in an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, since left adjoints preserve colimits.

In more detail, your second paragraph says that $\hom_{\mathbf{Top}}(\iota(X),Y)\cong \hom_{k \mathbf{Top}}(X,Y_k)$.
 Moreover these bijection are clearly natural (since they are identity at the level of functions). This means that $k$-ification is right adjoint to $\iota$ and hence $\iota$ preserves all colimits.